# Changing the position of the autolayout enabled control revert the changes?

Tags: ios, uicollectionview, autolayout

A part of my application is showing a list in UIcollectionView, if the user swipe down the screen I will present the UISearchBar with animation from the top of the viewController.
I did all of them in a separate viewController.

I use autolayout to position the controls in that viewController.

I move the search bar form y=-88 to y=0 and move the collectionView down to make space for searchBar with animation when the user swipe down the screen, my problem is that if I make call to reloadData to collectionView, both search bar and CollectionView move to their previous autolayouted positions

I use below animation to move them

```
[UIView animateWithDuration:0.4 animations:^(void){
        fileSearchBar.frame=fileSearchBar.frame=CGRectOffset(fileSearchBar.frame, 0,88);
        chartsCollectionView.frame=gridFrame;///gridFrame is calculated to move down
    }];
```

I there a way to stop them moving to their pre-calculated position

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you use auto layout, you must not set frames. You have to change constraints and let that change the frames indirectly.

Apple's Auto Layout Guide shows [an example](https://developer.apple.com/Library/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/AutolayoutPG/AutoLayoutbyExample/AutoLayoutbyExample.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010853-CH5-SW15) of animating:

```
[containerView layoutIfNeeded]; // Ensures that all pending layout operations have been completed
[UIView animateWithDuration:0.4 animations:^{
     // Make all constraint changes here
     [containerView layoutIfNeeded]; // Forces the layout of the subtree animation block and then captures all of the frame changes
}];
```

You don't show how you set up your constraints, so I can't show you how to modify them to move the search bar and collection view. Ideally, you'd just need to set the `constant` property of one of the constraints. (Your constraints should be set up so that moving one thing causes the other to adjust itself automatically.)