# Changing Xcode View Positions programatically with Autolayout enabled

Tags: objective-c, xcode, swift, autolayout, ios-autolayout

I am working on an Xcode 6 / Swift Project and I have noticed that when I enable Auto layout I can no longer set positions of my Views programatically. As an example I tried to override my AutoLayout Constraints on a View in `ViewDidLoad` and it did not work.

```
override func viewDidLoad() { 
super.viewDidLoad() 

// This Does not work 
self.myView.center = CGPointMake(150, 200)

}
```

How do I override Auto layout View Constraints Programatically?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26984892/xcode-storyboard-issue-with-auto-layout-not-allowing-me-to-move-an-objects-origi/26986138#26986138

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to add constraints if you are using auto layout and want specific position for any object.

At bottom right 4 icons there. You can use them for constraints.
[image]

or if you want to do this programetically

 then create IBOutlet of NSLayoutConstraint and set new value by doing this

```
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet NSLayoutConstraint *c1;
```

and

```
[UIView animateWithDuration:0.4 animations:^{
        self.c1.constant=500;
    }];
```

Comment: I understand that but what if you want to alter these Positions Programatically and animate views when a button is clicked for example?

Comment: then refer [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13744932/animating-moving-views-under-usage-of-autolayout) or [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25404829/changing-the-position-of-the-autolayout-enabled-control-revert-the-changes)

Comment: Go with edited answer it will surely help you
for IBOutlet of NSLayoutConstraint you must have to create constraint in storyboard once after that you can edit this constraint only.

Answer (score 1):

1- Create two constrains for the horizontal center and vertical center.

2- Connect these constraints from IB to your code.

3- Change the constant value of these constraints programmatically.

Comment: Is there a link which details this further or shows step by step process?